# Permission denied in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, icons, themes

I have a file which includes new icons for my system.

Anyway, How can I change my old icons down with new ones?
The name of the new icon pack is "myFAV-TUX" and it's sitting on my desktop.

The problem is, I can't copy them into the `usr/share/icons/` folder. It says, permission denied.

I also tried `ls -l` .... But i couldn't do it.

How can I change the icon theme? Please help.

Comment: lrn2unix...you need to use "sudo" before the commands above because they are administrative and modify system files.

Comment: Fixed up your question if you don't mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *also usr/share/icons havenot an permission to copy file into it*

open a terminal (Applications > Accessories > Terminal) and type

```
sudo nautilus
```

this should open the GUI folder structure but as a super user so you should be able to put your icons in the usr/share folder

I don't know if this will help you to switch the ubuntu theme?
this looks like a good tutorial
http://www.simplehelp.net/2009/05/26/how-to-install-ubuntu-themes/

Comment: i am not a idiot 

i know how i can change themes

i am asking how can i change icons without using ls -l and sudo cp because ls l..

doesnot work

Answer (score 5):

Okay gcc. You have to understand Linux first. On Windows, you got one user, one administrator. One simple account who can do **everything**.

On Linux, you basically start with TWO accounts (for security reasons). One user, this is what you get by default. And, *the* "admin", the root.

On Ubuntu, they disabled the "admin". However, you can enable it if you use some command.

If you want to switch to the admin account (so you can mess around with that /usr/share), type: `sudo su` .... There you go, you became root, yeah.

---

**HOWEVER**, and this is **IMPORTANT**: *You do NOT need that folder.* Simply, open your file browser, in your home folder. Press `CTRL+H`. Now, you see a LOTS of folders. Create a new one with the name of `.themes` (note the "."). After this, copy the icon folder there. Check your icon settings (Appereance, Edit, icons) and its there. ! That's all.

---

Also: I don't want to be rude, and seriously, this is just an advice. You should search with Google at times like this. Just type in the crucial words like: `how to install icon theme ubuntu`. You'll find a solution. It's faster, better, easier. Of course, I don't mind if you ask here, obviously not. But you'll need to help yourself out sometimes if you want to use a linux, and this is the very first step to get used to "Googleing".

Comment: Hi @Shiki I'm trying to install icons to the the `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/##x##/apps/` folder, so im trying to copy pngs there but it keeps giving me permission denied. Other then the sudo method, is there any method for this? Like making folder in the home directory would work as you did for theme above? I am looking for cross-linux-os solution, so not just ubuntu but mint, kaosx etc etc so i dont have nautilus here. Thanks!

Comment: @Noitidart - You can aleays install it as a user, and it will be only available for you only. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME#GTK.2B_themes_and_icon_themes

Comment: thank you!!! I will test that out, all I want is to install for just user! :) :) I'll test it and let you know how it works! :) Im hoping it works across all linux like this :)